# C++ -vector<string> in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a code in C++ as basically a class const and a dest

```
 Abc(vector<std::string>& names);
 virtual ~Abc();
```

I need to know the equilivalent in C#

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing that differentiates virtual destructors from ordinary destructors in C# -- it's all virtual.

Comment: Do you want to write equivalent code in C#, or do you want to interoperate between C# and C++ (basically, call this code from C#)?

Answer (score 2):

in C#, you could just write this:

```
Abc(List<string> names);
```

and there is no use of `~Abc()` in C#. It has garbage collector.

However, if your class manages resource, then derive `Abc` from `IDisposable` and implement `Dispose()` method which is somewhat similar to `~Abc()`:

```
class Abc : IDisposable
{
     Abc(ref List<string> names);
     void Dispose();       
}
```

Comment: @LindaHarrison `Abc(ref List<string> names);`

Comment: `ref` is not needed in C#. Every reference type is automatically passed 'by reference'. As it stands now this answer is wrong, would more be equivalent to `Abc(vector<std::string>&* names)` (IIRC)

Comment: @jeroenh: I was thinking the same, but then I added `ref` because of the first comment. I also think, C# doesn't have exact equivalent to `std::vector<std::string> &`. So we have to settle on some side, either with `ref` or without it. Both seem okay to me.

Comment: With ref, the intention in C# is to *change the reference* in the called method, i.e. assign an entirely new `List<T>`. Without ref, you simply pass the list (as a reference) to the method (and can still add/remove stuff to it obviously). So definitely the ref is to be removed.